# Timeout Elasticsearch Centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, centos

During Installation of ElasticSearch : I am having problem when I try to start the elastcsearch service with this timeout problem. I am new to this particular topic and the how can I increase the timeout. What file to use. I am novice now please bear with me. I have looked at the elasticsearch.yml and nothing like TIMEOUT in it.

error message :
**Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

In addition when I tried sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service  it gives this error :

**Failed to execute operation: Bad message**

Comment: what this command gives `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: Thank you @OpsterElasticsearchNinja. I have unintalled elastic search and resintall using another method. It is now working. I followed this link https://www.tecmint.com/install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-rhel-7/